# drag & drop content without move itself, but only scrolls of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, drag-and-drop

I want to be abble to drag & drop my content (div) in a div with overflow:auto and scrolls, but instead of move content itself like draggable() in jQuery, I need to move only scrolls.

exemple with jQuery :

```
$('#map').draggable();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ub5e21L/

now I want same result but move only scrolls when I drag & drop with my mouse, and never move the `div#map` itself.

how can I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to set `#main { overflow: hidden; }`?

Comment: no, I want to see scrolls, but like you move it with wheel mouse, I want move scroll by drag & drop.